# Use Allure "Issue" annotation in a custom way (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, automated-tests, allure

In my team, we're using Allure reports for our Selenium tests.
In some of our tests, we use the "Issue" annotation to record the bugs related to the test.
I would like to use this annotation to do something particular everytime the machine runs a test which is bugged (let's say: log something in the console).
What should I do in order to achieve this? Is it even possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on test framework you are using, there are ways to handle and/or transform annotations.

e.g. for TestNG you can use [fixture](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) `@BeforeMethod` to handle `@Issue` annotation

```
@BeforeMethod
public void issueAnnotationProcessing(Method m) {
    if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Issue.class)) {
        Issue issue = m.getAnnotation(Issue.class);
        System.out.println("Test contains issue: " + issue.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the type of stuff I was looking for, but too bad, it didn't work in my non-TestNG project... I did import the required libraries and put the method in the abstract test class, it's just not called. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: JUnit has `@Rule` and `@Before` fixtures as well, maybe those can offer similar functionality. Can't help with example, unfortunately, as I'm not as familiar with JUnit as with TestNG